# How to increase size for textbox control XAML

Tags: css, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I need to increase the size of 'X' in textbox control.

What is the styling property name?

FontSize property only changes the size for the font and setting width/height for textbox won't change the size for clear button on the right.

[image]

Comment: You need to edit the default style of the `TextBox`.

Comment: That was my question. What is that styling property name?

Comment: @Dave Have you solved your issue by Justin XL's solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to duplicate the [default style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299154.aspx) of the `TextBox`.

Then go find this element -

```
<TextBlock x:Name="GlyphElement"
           AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
           Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForeground}"
           FontStyle="Normal"
           FontSize="12"
           FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           Text="&#xE10A;"
           VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

Note the `FontSize` is set to `12`. Change it to -

```
FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
```

Now, the `FontSize` of the `GlyphElement` will be in sync with the `FontSize` of its templated parent (i.e. `DeleteButton`) of which `FontSize` is then in sync with its templated parent `TextBox`.

If you now increase the `FontSize` of your `TextBox`, you will see both the text and the **X** get bigger.